# Big rearrangement theorem/Big associative law

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Translated from German Großes Assoziativgesetz/Grpßer Umordnungssatz.

I am currently reading the textbook analysis 1 from Konrad Königsberger. It is page 70 I have Problems with.

I don't know the englisch expressions but the chapter I am currently reading is called "Summierbare Familien". Summable families.

**Definitions**

Let $I$ be a nonempty set and $a:I\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a set. $a$ or also $(a)_{i\in I}$ is called a Family and $a_i$ is defined as $a(i)$. The set of all finite subsets of $I$ is defined as $\mathscr{E}(I)$. For $J\in\mathscr{E}(I)$ define

$$a_J:=\sum_{i\in J}a_i\quad |a|_J:=\sum_{i\in J}|a_i|$$

$a_J$ is then the partialsum of the Family $a$ to the indexset $J$.

A Family $(a)_{i\in I}$ is called summable if there is a $s\in\mathbb{C}$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite indexset $I_{\epsilon}\subset I$ such that for all $J\subset \mathscr{E}(I)$ with $I_{\epsilon}\subseteq J$ we have

$$|s-a_J|\leq \epsilon$$

$s$ is then called the sum of the Family $a$ and also written as $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$.

**Already proven facts**

*A family has not more than one sum*

*By Definition if* $\pi:I\rightarrow I$ *is a permutation then $\sum_{i\in I}a_{\pi(i)}=\sum_{i\in I}a_i$*

*Test for summability: A family $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ is summable if and only if the set $\{|a|_J \, |\,J\in\mathscr{E}(I) \}$ of partialsums from the family $|a|$ is bounded*

*Rearangementtheorem: A family $a=(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is summable if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$ converges absolutely. The respecitive sums are equal in this case*

$$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$$

**Theorem**

> The big rearrangement Theorem states that if $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ is
>   summable and $I_k$, $k\in K$ are pairwise disjoint subsets of $I$ such
>   that the union of those is $I$ again. Then every subfamily
>   $(a_i)_{i\in I_k}$ is summable and the family $(s_k)_{k\in K}$ of the
>   sums $s_k:=\sum_{i\in I_k}a_i$ is sumable and we have
>
> $$\fbox{$\sum_{i\in I}a_i=\sum_{k\in K}s_k=\sum_{k\in K}\big(\sum_{i\in I_k}a_i\big)$}$$

Proof:

The summability of the subfamilies results from the summability test. The summablity of  the family $(s_k)_{k\in K}$ also results from the summabilty test. Because if we take an arbitrary finite subset $\{k_1,...,k_n\}\subset K$ we can make the estimate

$$\sum_{v=1}^{n}|s_{k_{v}}|\leq \sum_{v=1}^{n}\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}=\sup_{(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})}
\big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}\leq \sup_{J\in\mathscr{E}(I)}\{|a|_J\}$$

To prove the Formula we set $S:=\sum_{i\in I}a_i$. Furthermore let $\epsilon>0$. We then have to find a finite indexset such that with $S_M:=\sum_{k\in M}s_k$ we have

$$\tag{*}|S_m-S|\leq \epsilon\quad \text{for all }M\in\mathscr{E}(K) \text{ with } K_\epsilon \subset M $$

According to the the deinition of $S$ there is a finite indexset $I_{\epsilon}\subset I$ such that $|a_J-S|\leq \epsilon/2$ for alll $J\in\mathscr{E}(I)$ with $I_\epsilon \subset J$. To $I_\epsilon$ we choose a finite set $K_\epsilon\subset K$ such that the union of $I_k,\, k\in K_{\epsilon}$ contains $I_\epsilon$. We now Show that $K_\epsilon$ satisfies $(*)$. If $m$ is the number of Elements in $M$, we choose for every subfamily $(a_i)_{i\in I_k}$ a dinite subset $I_{k,\epsilon}\subset I_k$ with

$$|a_{I_{k,\epsilon}}-s_k|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2m}\quad\text{ and } \quad (I_k\cap I_{\epsilon})\subset I_{k,\epsilon}$$

For $|S_M-S|$ we get the estimate:

$$|\sum_{k\in M}s_k-S|\leq \sum_{k\in M}|s_k-a_{I_{k,\epsilon}}-S|\leq m\frac{\epsilon}{2m}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon;$$

for that we used that $\bigcup_{k\in M}I_{k,\epsilon}=:J$ is a union of disjoint sets hence $a_J=\sum_{k\in M}a_{I_{k,\epsilon}}$ and that $|a_J-S|\leq \epsilon/2$ because $J$ contains according to the construction $I_{\epsilon}$ $\square$

**Question:**

I could only understand the first line of the proof and I was really trying hard to understand this estimate:

$$\sum_{v=1}^{n}|s_{k_{v}}|\leq \sum_{v=1}^{n}\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}=\sup_{(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})}
\big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}\leq \sup_{J\in\mathscr{E}(I)}\{|a|_J\}$$

I am not sure about the other parts but I think I could somehow figure it out because all is jstified. If not I will have to open a new Question or eddit this Question again.

Why is

$$|s_{k_{v}}|\leq\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}$$

And also the equality, how can I prove it?

$$\sum_{v=1}^n\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}=\sup_{(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})}
\big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}$$

For the last inequality I have got an idea:

If I take an arbitrary $J_v\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})$ and we look at $\sum_{v=1}^{n}|a|_{J_v}$ then since each $J_v$ is also an element of $\mathscr{E}(I)$ we can also express $\sum_{v=1}^{n}|a|_{J_v}$ as $\sum_{i\in J} |a_i|=|a|_J$ for some $J$. which is less or equal than $\sup_{J\in\mathscr{E}(I)}\{|a|_J\}$.

I don't know how I can argue such that also we can establish the case for $\sup_{(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})}
\big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}$ ?

Please help me and let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: The expression $\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}$ is bad notation: the variable $v$ is used before the sum. Maybe the index set in this term should not be denoted by $J_v$ but with something else.

Comment: @supinf Maybe $\sup_{(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})}$ ? Is that what it was supposed to mean?

Comment: that is possible. At least, then the inequality and equality involving this term should be true, i think.

Comment: I completed my answer after your modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is 
>   $$|s_{k_{v}}|\leq\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}$$

Basically its a form of the triangle inequality.

Let $\epsilon>0$.
Let $I_\epsilon\subset I$ be a finite index set 
such that for all $J\subset \mathscr{E}(I_{k_v})$ with $I_{\epsilon}\subseteq J$ we have 
$|s_{k_v}-a_J|\leq \epsilon$.
Then $|s_{k_v}|\leq |a_J|+\epsilon$ follows by inverse triangle inequality.
By the triangle inequality, we also have $|a_J|\leq |a|_J$, since the latter is a finite sum.
Now this implies
$$|s_{k_{v}}|\leq\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}+\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was aribtrary, the inequality
$$|s_{k_{v}}|\leq\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}.$$
follows.

> And also the equality, how can I prove it?
>   $$\sum_{v=1}^n\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}=\sup_{(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})}
> \big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}$$

The right-hand side can be rewritten as
$$
\sup_{J_1\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_1})} \sup_{J_2\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_2})} \cdots 
\sup_{J_n\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_n})} \big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}.
$$
Now both terms contain $n$ supremums. It can be seen that $\sup_{J_1\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_1})}$
can be exchanged with $\sum$:
$$
\sum_{v=1}^n\sup_{J_v\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})}\{|a|_{J_{v}}\}
= 
\sup_{J_1\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_1})} |a|_{J_1} +
\sup_{J_2\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_2})} |a|_{J_2} + \cdots
\sup_{J_n\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_n})} |a|_{J_n}
= 
\sup_{J_1\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_1})} \left(
|a|_{J_1} +
\sup_{J_2\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_2})} |a|_{J_2} + \cdots
\sup_{J_n\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_n})} |a|_{J_n}
\right).
$$
If you repeat this process for $v=2,\dots n$ you can get the equality that you want.

> For the last inequality I have got an idea:
>   If I take an arbitrary $J_v\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{v}})$ and we look at $\sum_{v=1}^{n}|a|_{J_v}$ then since each $J_v$ is also an element of $\mathscr{E}(I)$ we can also express $\sum_{v=1}^{n}|a|_{J_v}$ as $\sum_{i\in J} |a_i|=|a|_J$ for some $J$. which is less or equal than $\sup_{J\in\mathscr{E}(I)}\{|a|_J\}$.

This is a good idea.
It can be improved by starting with an arbitrary
$(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})$.
Then you have shown that
$$
\big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}\leq \sup_{J\in\mathscr{E}(I)}\{|a|_J\}
$$
is true.
Since
$(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})$
was chosen arbitrary, you can also just take the supremum over those $(J_1,\dots,J_n)$ in the inequality.
The result is then
$$
\sup_{(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})}
\big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}\leq \sup_{J\in\mathscr{E}(I)}\{|a|_J\}.
$$

Comment: Why can you rewrite $\sup_{(J_1,...,J_n)\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_{1}})\times … \times \mathscr{E}(I_{k_{n}})}\big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}$ as $\sup_{J_1\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_1})} \sup_{J_2\in\mathscr{E}(I_{k_2})} \cdots 
\sup_{J_n\in \mathscr{E}(I_{k_n})} \big\{\sum_{v=1}^n|a|_{J_{v}}\big\}.
$ ? In the first Formula you only choose one tuple in the second Formula you make $n$ choices. Why is it the same?

Comment: More generally why $\sup_{(a_1,...,a_n)\in A_1\times…\times A_n}\{f(a_1,...,a_n)\}=\sup_{a_1\in A_1}…\sup_{a_n\in A_n}\{f(a_1,...,a_n)\}$? What does the righthandside mean?

Comment: because the variables $a_1,\dots$ are independent of each other and a choice $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ corresponds directly to the $n$ choices $a_1,\in A_1, \dots, a_n\in A_n$.

Comment: This Notation is a bit confusing to me I have tried to make an induction proof myself if $f_1:A_1\rightarrow \mathbb{R},...,f_n:A_n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then $\sup_{x_1\in A_1}\{f_1(x_1)\}+....+\sup_{x_n\in A_n}\{f_n(x_n)\}=\sup_{(x_1,...,x_n)\in A_1\times … \times A_n}\{f_1(x)+...+f_n(x_n)\}$ The inductionbase is true. Inductionstep follows because due to the inductionhypothesis we have  $\sup_{x_1\in A_1}\{f_1(x_1)\}+....+\sup_{x_n\in A_n}\{f_n(x_n)\}+\sup_{x_{n+1}}\{f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})\}=\sup_{(x_1,...,x_n)\in A_1\times … \times A_n}\{f_1(x)+...+f_n(x_n)\}+\sup_{x_{n+1}}\{f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})\}$

Comment: One can then prove that $\sup_{x\in P}\{f(x)\}+\sup_{y\in Q}\{g(y)\}=\sup_{(x,y)\in P\times Q}\{f(x)+g(y)\}$ for $f:P\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:Q\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then if $f:(A_1\times …\times A_n)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\, ,f(x_1,...,x_n)=f_1(x_1)+...f_n(x_n)$ adn $g=f_{n+1}$ the Proposition follows. If there is something wrong please tell me.

Comment: the last two comments from you are correct.